# Search posts/video/images/etc by tag (facebook api 2.0+)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Will Facebook make function to search posts/video/images/etc by tag (in api 2.0+)?
Does Keyword Insights API can do such search? With whom can I communicate about use Keyword Insights API?